# python​ Opencv​2​ show​ image​ and​ the​ same time​ call​ other​ function

Tags: python, opencv

I​ want​ show​ image​ window​ and​ the​ same time​ call​ other​ function.

Ex.

```py
img = cv2.imread("file.png") 
cv2.imshow("window", img) 
cv2.waitkey(0)

def call_function()​:   
    while​ True:
        print("hello")​
```

Comment: There can be different solutions. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I​ want​ show​ image.​And​ use​ while​ True​ loop​ for​ read​ ID card​ then i​ will​ chang image​ in​ same window.

Answer (score 0):

Show image in "read ID" loop:

```
img = cv2.imread("file.png")
img1 = cv2.imread("file1.png")
while True:
    # Read id stuff here
    if id_ready:
        img=img1

    cv2.imshow("window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Thank​ you.i will​ try.<3<3

Answer (score -1):

If​ i​ want​ query​ database​ in​ this​ loop.
I​ think it use​ time about 2​second.
It response to​ window​ show​​ image​ slowly.
How​ can​ i​ fix this.
Ex.​ I​ use​ time.sleep​ repace query​ing ​database
import​ time
img = cv2.imread("file.png")
img1 = cv2.imread("file1.png")
while True:
# Read id stuff here
time.sleep(2)
if id_ready:
img=img1

```
cv2.imshow("window", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: In this case you have to query​ database​ in separate thread. Search by "python multithreading" keywords.

Comment: Thank​ you.​ Do​ you​ think multithreading  can​ use​ in​ this​ case? <3<3